# groovy multithreading

Tags: multithreading, grails, groovy

I'm newbie to groovy/grails.

How to implement thread for this code . Had 2500 urls and this was taking hours of time for checking each url.

so i decided to implement multi-thread for this :

Here is my sample code :

```
def urls = [
  "http://www.wordpress.com",
  "http://67.192.103.225/QRA.Public/" ,
  "http://www.subaru.com",
  "http://baldwinfilter.com/products/start.html"
]

def up = urls.collect { ur ->
    try {
        def url = new URL(ur)
        def connection = url.openConnection()
        if (connection.responseCode == 200) {
            return true
        } else {
            return false
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false
    } 
}
```

**For this code i need to implement multi-threading** .
Could any one please suggest me the code.

thanks in advance,
sri.

Answer (score 11):

I would take a look at the [Groovy Parallel Systems](http://gpars.codehaus.org/) library.  In particular I think that the [Parallel collections](http://www.gpars.org/guide/guide/3.%20Parallel%20Collections.html) section would be useful.

Looking at the docs, I believe that collectParallel is a direct drop-in replacement for collect (bearing in mind the obvious caveats about side-effects).  The following works fine for me:

```
def urls = [
  "http://www.wordpress.com",
  "http://www.subaru.com",
  "http://baldwinfilter.com/products/start.html"
]
Parallelizer.doParallel {
    def up = urls.collectParallel { ur ->
        try {
            def url = new URL(ur)
            def connection = url.openConnection()
            if (connection.responseCode == 200) {
                return true
            } else {
                return false
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return false
        }
    }
    println up
}
```

Comment: Hi mojones , could you please provide me with small example similar to my need.I have gone through the docs .

Comment: I've edited my original answer to include an example since I don't think I can use code formatting in a comment.

Comment: One additional note: you can pass a parameter to collectParallel giving the number of threads to use; you'll probably want to set that to a large number in case you get a bunch of servers that take a long time to return a status code.

Answer (score 3):

[See the Groovy docs](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Concurrency+with+Groovy) for an example how to use an `ExecutorService` to do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this to check the URL in a separate thread.

```
class URLReader implements Runnable
{
    def valid
    def url

    URLReader( url ) {
        this.url = url
    }

    void run() {
        try {
            def connection = url.toURL().openConnection()
            valid = ( connection.responseCode == 200 ) as Boolean
        } catch ( Exception e ) {
            println e.message
            valid = Boolean.FALSE
        }
    }
}
def reader = new URLReader( "http://www.google.com" )
new Thread( reader ).start()
while ( reader.valid == null )
{
    Thread.sleep( 500 )
}
println "valid: ${reader.valid}"
```

Notes: The valid attribute will be either null, Boolean.TRUE or Boolean.FALSE. You'll need to wait for a while to give all the threads a chance to open the connection. Depending on the number of URLs you're checking you will eventually hit a limit of the number of threads / connections you can realistically handle, so should check URLs in batches of the appropriate size.

Comment: thanks Andrew. I tried with your solution with minor changes.I created  groovy class with name ValidateLinks which extends Thread . This is working but unable to run thread when exceeds urls count 400 + . Please view my new answer posted .

Answer (score 1):

I think this way is very simple to achieve.

---

```
import java.util.concurrent.*

//Thread number
THREADS = 100
pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(THREADS)
defer = { c -> pool.submit(c as Callable) }

def urls = [
  "http://www.wordpress.com",
  "http://www.subaru.com",
]

def getUrl = { url ->
  def connection = url.openConnection()
  if (connection.responseCode == 200) {
    return true
  } else {
    return false
  }
}


def up = urls.collect { ur ->
    try {
        def url = new URL(ur)
    defer{ getUrl(url) }.get()
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false
    } 
}

println up
pool.shutdown()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I implemented:

```
class ValidateLinks extends Thread{
    def valid
    def url

    ValidateLinks( url ) {
        this.url = url
    }

    void run() {
        try {
            def connection = url.toURL().openConnection()
        connection.setConnectTimeout(5000)
            valid = ( connection.responseCode == 200 ) as Boolean
        } catch ( Exception e ) {
            println url + "-" + e.message
            valid = Boolean.FALSE
        }
    }
}

def threads = [];
urls.each { ur ->
def reader = new ValidateLinks(ur.site_url)
reader.start()
threads.add(reader);
}

while (threads.size() > 0) {

        for(int i =0; i < threads.size();i++) {
                def tr = threads.get(i);
                if (!tr.isAlive()) {
                        println "URL : " + tr.url  + "Valid " + tr.valid
                        threads.remove(i);
                        i--;

                }
        }
}
```